# Javascript module design patterns

Tags: javascript, class-design, architectural-patterns

Partly for use in my own projects, and partly for fun while being stuck at home I'm attempt to build yet another "block" based editor.

So far I've been using simple objects, starting with a global `window.myeditor` object, then various sub objects to handle different things. For example I have `window.myeditor.toolbar` to abstract functions for creating toolbars in each block. I also have made use of `Object.create` to extend my base `window.myeditor.block` object to create different block types (paragraph/heading/etc), then create instances of these objects for each element on the page.

It's starting to get a bit messy though. I can't use global variables in the objects as these don't get re-instantiated with `Object.create` and so all my objects end up seeing the exact same variables, not a big issue but isn't ideal. I'm also creating functions like `_focus()` in my main block object, which does some standard stuff, then calling `focus()` from inside there, which is a function designed to be replaced by child objects so they can extend that functionality. I'm also finding myself duplicating code (such as code to make bold/italic work) which I could probably centralise if I had a more well defined way of "modularising" the logic.

Looking at how other projects work, it seems building on classes, most likely via modules, is the current favourite, although I'm having problems getting my head around a base implementation and think I'm just screwing up the basic architecture.

For example at the moment I have something along the lines of the following -

`Editor` class/module with a global instance to handle the main editor (not that it's required but I'd ideally design it such that nothing relies on having a global instance to anything, so that multiple editor instances would actually be possible without messing each other up). That instance contains an instance of `BlockRegistry` which stores the different types of block and a reference to their class. The editor also has an array of `BlockContainer` instances which control a section of blocks on the page. There is a base `Block` class to handle a single content block that should be extended by plugin block types.

The `BlockContainer` class need to list all the html sub-elements, and create a `SomeBlockTypeThatExtendsBlock` instance for them, using the correct handler, but in order to do that, it needs to access to the `BlockRegistry` instance to see if it's a supported block type and the correct class.

I can see myself getting this issue of various class instances needing access to features of other instances regularly, but not sure what the correct method here is, other than resorting to constantly accessing the global instance from inside modules, passing references all over the place, or just sticking any code that might need to reference something else in the same place.

I think I'm just missing something obvious and screwing up the basic design.

Comment: *"but in order to do that, it needs to access to the BlockRegistry instance to see if it's a supported block type and the correct class."* - and why precisely is this an issue? Or the statement *"various class instances needing access to features of other instances"* - that is not an issue per se. It might become in issue if a single object requires to access to features of *too many* other instances, but "too many" is  to some degree opinionated. Honestly, this is IMHO unanswerable with the shown 20.000 feet view, without seeing the actual code. ...

Comment: Maybe you should pick a piece of code which looks "suspicious" to you and ask a question on codereview.SE about it?